# FileHelpers change RecordLine before reading the record

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am reading a huge file using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net) library. I would like to change the RecordLine before reading the record like below.

```
   static void engine_BeforeReadRecord(object sender, BeforeReadRecordEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (e.RecordLine.Contains(@"\|"))
            e.RecordLine.Replace(@"\|", "");
    }
```

Their online help also says it is possible to change

```
Note: if you change the RecordLine the engine use the changed value
This can be useful in some cases but you must be carefull
```

But it is not working. Whether any issue in the way am i doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last version of the library you can do that

http://www.filehelpers.net/download/

You can also use the INotifyRead interface:

http://www.filehelpers.net/example/EventsAndNotification/INotifyRead/

Comment: Thanks Marcos, I will download the latest version and try this with assignment.

Comment: The latest version with Joel's answer works pefectly. Thanks for the wonderful library you have provided.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming RecordLine is a string, you call the `.Replace()` function, but this function does not modify a string inline — it returns a new string.  You need to assign the result somewhere:

```
if (e.RecordLine.Contains(@"\|"))
    e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Replace(@"\|", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, I tried this earlier and it showed an error that e.RecordLine is read-only.

Comment: @RajanR.G In that case you need to use both my answer and MarcosMeli's. Also - there's no need for the if statement - if the string does not contain the text, the replace call will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks Joel, the latest version with your resolution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're setting the event?

```
engine.BeforeReadRecord += engine_BeforeReadRecord;
```